возможно ли прочитать sqlite базу данных БЕЗ библиотеки sqlite3?
Мне нужно просто прочитать базу данных sqlite, точнее одну таблицу, в цикое пробежаться по каждому полю а потом получить в виде строки все что содержит данное поле
возможно ли подобное сделать без библиотеки sqlite3 на c++?
(нашел upx, который мне подходит)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
=>
Рассмотрите альтернативные подходы,
такие как использование других библиотек для работы с базами данных или перенос данных в другой формат, потому как формат файла
вручную может быть крайне сложным и подверженным ошибкам.

Можно, но зачем??? Ведь библиотека весит всего несколько метров. / А так, идёте в документацию, изучаете Database File Format, пишете свой парсер... Думаю, к новому году управитесь (какого именно года - не уточняю).

@AlexanderPetrov либка очень много весит, а мне такое нельзя ^-^ (~9мб исходник, ~1.3мб компилированный) а вся прога должна уложиться в 500кб максимум, и у меня получается, но если без либки sqlite

Тогда данные из SQLite перегоните в другой формат, например, csv или json. И потом работайте с ним.

@AlexanderPetrov есть ли уже готовое решение?

Export to CSV

@AlexanderPetrov опять же, я должен делать это самой программой, а подключать такую тяжелую по объему занимаемого места библиотеку sqlite я не могу, и делаю я ее под винду, то есть я никак не смогу там скачать с интернета в папочку temp эту библиотеку, ну по типу такого

facepalm.avi (20 gb)... Это делается один раз в консоли (шеле)! Не нужно ничего никуда подключать. После экспорта данных юзайте их в своей крошечной программке.

Если это винда (а не какая-то embedded железка), то почему важен размер бинарника?

@HolyBlackCat надо так

Как вы собираетесь использовать upx? Сжать свою программу с подключенной sqlite.dll? / Не пишите решение в самом вопросе. Оформите ответ как положено.

У вас три варианта на выбор:

Не страдать фигнёй, а подключить dll, за пару минут написать код и пойти пить... чай.

Изучить Database File Format, написать свой парсер этого формата, на что может понадобиться от нескольких недель до нескольких лет.

Экспортировать данные из БД в другой формат, который можно будет легко употребить в вашей программе.


Давайте этим и займёмся.
Идём на SQLite Download Page, качаем Precompiled Binaries for Windows с утилитой командной строки.
Запускаем sqlite3.exe.
Открываем вашу БД:
.open test.db

Вместо test.db укажите имя вашего файла.
В документации смотрим раздел Export to CSV. Выполняем приведённые там команды:
.headers on
.mode csv
.once data.csv
SELECT * FROM tablename;

Это сохранит данные из указанной таблицы в указанный файл в желаемом формате.
Вместо data.csv укажите желаемое имя и путь.
Выберите правильную таблицу.
При необходимости задайте нужные столбцы в SELECT.
Вместо csv можно задать любой другой поддерживаемый формат, с которым вам будет удобней работать, например, json.
После этого можно удалить скачанные ранее файлы sqlite. Также можете удалить саму базу данных.
Теперь файл с данными (csv/json) положите в папку вашей программы (или по известному пути) и читайте данные из него.
На всё про всё нужно не более нескольких минут.

спасибо, первый вариант мне подошел, потому что я узнал про Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
